# Wildfly - Managed Scheduled Executor Threads in Kubernetes

Tags: multithreading, kubernetes, wildfly, threadpool

I'm using Wildfly application server (v. **23.0.1**), deployed in a pod inside a Kubernetes cluster.
In my app, I am using ManagedScheduledExecutorService to start different Kafka Consumers in separate threads. I have noticed a strange behaviour:

**In k8s setup**, it seems that I can have **at most** **2 threads** up and running.
No matter how many threads I specify in *core-threads* argument inside *standalone-full.xml*, the app can support only 2 threads. As a result, I can use at most 2 different Kafka consumers.

When I deploy **locally** the same app (**dockerized only**) it seems that I can use much more threads (tested up to 9 separate threads so far).

So is there something in Kubernetes that limits managed-scheduled-executor number of threads (I have read that core-threads = 2*processors), a matter of resources maybe? If nothing could be done on the subject, is there any other thread-pool similar to managed-scheduled-executor that could do the job?

Comment: Are you sure the configuration is correctly applied in the k8s setup? With 2 being the default value for this, it seems a bit suspicious.

Comment: Well my devops skills are limited, so I cannot understand which k8s configuration could possibly affect this. No matter how many core-threads I use in standalone-full.xml only 2 are available in k8s. Could you think of any config in k8s that might cause this issue? Let me also say that we have another microservice in the same k8s cluster that works ok, but the underlying application server is OpenLiberty. It is the wildfly+k8s combination that causes the problem imo.

Comment: There is no concept in Kubernetes that limit the number of available threads. Even when you limit the CPU resources available to the pod, it limits the available CPU time. So my guess is that this a configuration issue. Can you describe how you are setting this parameter and share any relevant config or scripts?